# What will happen if two different programs try to write to the same file simulatneously?

Tags: file-locking

1. What will happen if two different
   programs try to write to the same
   file simultaneously?
2. Will one of the programs experience
   a file lock error?
3. How should programs be designed to
   handle this scenario?

Comment: This is OS-specific. Which one are you concerned about ?

Comment: @philippe: I am concerned only about Microsoft Windows based OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the second app (or thread) try to open the file for writing it would throw IO exception.. simple..

Comment: You can first put your file opening code in a try catch block.. if its successful then you write.. if not you prompt the user or try again after a certain interval.. Or you can try using "DATABASE" where multiple apps can modify it at same time..

Answer (score 0):

Use FileLock to avoid IO Exception when file is being accessed by multiple threads.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is "FileLock"?

Comment: please go through below link http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html

Comment: you Just mentioned tag as "File-locking" you should have mention it as ".net" too. Answer what i have answered is applicable for all the languages where syncronised concept applicable and in the comment i mentioned as example. So please change reputaion from -1 to 0 .

Comment: @user668970 : I did not change reputation

Answer (score 0):

say you have user A and user B, what you can do is, let both of them modify the content, there will be a small difference in time however "simultaneous" you want it to be, so check which user has "submitted" the changes first, save those changes and prompt a smart message to the next user saying "file has been updated, check changes before.. blah blah".